# Java Comparing elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I'm creating a textbased noughts and crosses game in java and want to determine winning situations. I have used an array for the board such as String [] board :-

[0][1][2]

[3][4][5]

[6][7][8]

I have a whole list of possibilities that checks if 3 values in a row are the same in if statements.

This is an example of what i have:

```
if ((board [0] != "" && board [0] == board [1] && board [1] == board [2])) {
return true
}
```

Is there a way that does the same thing with a less amount of code?

Thanks

Comment: if it is string you should use equals method for comparison instead of  board [0] != ""

Comment: First step.  Know what `==` on strings really means in Java....

Answer (score 2):

Your idea can be made sound either by

- Using `.equals()` instead of `==` if you are really storing strings, or
- Store *characters* instead of strings, in which case `==` is safe.

Now if you are really making a noughts and crosses game, you have 8 different winning conditions, which, if you grow your current style of coding will have the form (here I am assuming characters, not strings):

```
winner = 
    (b[0] != ' ' && b[0] == b[1] && b[1] == b[2]) || 
    (b[3] != ' ' && b[3] == b[4] && b[4] == b[5]) ||
    ...
    (b[0] != ' ' && b[0] == b[4] && b[4] == b[8]);
```

There *are* other ways to do this; I'm sure a google search for tic-tac-toe or naughts and crosses implementations will show you quite a few.

If you would like to get fancy, there is a well-known technique of "labeling" each cell with a power of two.  Then by adding up the scores (i.e., looking at the player's bit vector) and doing a binary AND on the set of eight winning conditions you can determine a winning position in one shot.

Here is a comment block for a tic-tac-toe game that illustrates the technique.  (You didn't ask for actual *code*, so I'm withholding *that* from the answer):

```
/*
 * To determine a win condition, each square is "tagged"
 * from left to right, top to bottom, with successive
 * powers of 2.  Each cell thus represents an individual
 * bit in a 9-bit string, and a player's squares at any
 * given time can be represented as a unique 9-bit value.
 * A winner can thus be easily determined by checking
 * whether the player's current 9 bits have covered any
 * of the eight "three-in-a-row" combinations.
 *
 *     273                 84
 *        \               /
 *          1 |   2 |   4  = 7
 *       -----+-----+-----
 *          8 |  16 |  32  = 56
 *       -----+-----+-----
 *         64 | 128 | 256  = 448
 *       =================
 *         73   146   292
 *
 */
var wins = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84];
```

This was JavaScript.  For Java, use

```
private static final int[] WINS = new int[]{7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84};
```

Apologies if the binary logic approach here is not what you want; I thought it would be a good place to show it off though, in case others land on this page.

Comment: +1, it may not be what the OP was expecting, but it **does** do the same thing with less code

Comment: Thanks for the answer... does help. i know i didnt as for the code, but having seen this im curious to see the code. any chance you can share that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing your data? As Strings? "X" and "O"? or as numbers? 0, 1?

Like others said if you use Strings (an object) the `==` operator *will not work*!. You'd want to use `board[0].equals(....)` for `==` and `!board.equals(...)` for `!=`.

Having said that, using Strings is really not flexable for testing scenarios. I did tic-tac-toe in highschool so I know your pain. Using copy & paste it really doesn't take that long to write a large if-statement to check all rows/columns/diagnals. Five or ten minutes tops.

If you're more interested in compact code you might want to consider using numbers since you can use math to check conditions...

`if (row is not empty) and

    ((sum of indexes in row == 3) player 1 wins) or

     (sum of indexes in row == 0) player 2 wins

    )`

Get the idea?

Also, one tip I would suggest is using a two dimensional array (`String[][]`) so you can check on rows/columns easier!

Comment: Or better use equalsIgnoreCase() if by any chance "X" and "O" are being stored as "x" and "o"...Greater flexibility...

Comment: because of my beginner compentency in java, im using single arrays just to get an idea on it. when you say (sum of indexes in row == 3), how would you code the fact that 'sum of indexes in row' as there are 8 possible winning situations available? Thanks

Comment: @uncleB Sorry... when I talk about the math/integer based approach I was just giving an example off the top of my head. There are alternatives posted around I'm sure you can find if you google "tic-tac-toe code". *My* code example is in regards to taking the 3 squares in a row (say array elements, 0, 1, 2 for the top row) and then adding together their contents. (board[0]+board[1]+board[2]) and checking the value. If it is 3 then the "1" player won, if its 0 the "0" player won. If its either 1 or 2 then the row has some other combination that isn't a win...